# Vue.js. Which better to use event bus or storage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 components on the page. One of them is filters and other is list of results.

Two components have been made in reasons:
1. They are too large to use in single component
2. Made them separately. I can use list component without filters.

Now components are communicated via [Bus event](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). And my question is: "Do I continue to use bus event or delete it and make via vuex storage?".

P.S. I would like to hear real еips with explanations

P.S.S. Please don't write something like "you are idiot" and etc.

Comment: Are you going to do manipulation on the data you're sending between the 2 components? Or is it just a action-reaction type of event?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Non-flux-state-management-use-with-caution `Vuex should be preferred for global state management, instead of this.$root or a global event bus.

Managing state on this.$root and/or using a global event bus can be convenient for very simple cases, but are not appropriate for most applications. Vuex offers not only a central place to manage state, but also tools for organizing, tracking, and debugging state changes.`

Comment: @ErikTerwan action-reaction type of event

Comment: @JacobGoh a have read docs. But I wrote my code before i read about vuex. That's why i have asked my question, to know do I need rewrite my code or there no any difference to performance.

Comment: Performance wise, I don't know which one is faster but there won't be a noticeable difference unless your app is handling a huge amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's a matter of analyzing your needs. 
I usually think like this:

If it's a simple event that only happens there, use the bus.
If those filters are used other than in the parent, store them.
Vuex is already in place and every logic is stored, store it for sake of consistency.